# Find bounding box coordinates for a geometric shape

Tags: json, math, geometry, bounding-box

I have a JSON file that contains the geometric information about the sketch. The file is in the following format:

- `"Name"`: Name of the geometric entity
- `"Type"`: Type of the entity, either a line or an arc (a circle is represented by an arc and a rectangle as a set of 4 such dictionaries of type line.)

If the entity is of the type line, then the dict would contain the coordinates of the starting and ending points of the line.

If it is of the type arc, then the dict would contain the radius, the coordinates of the center and the starting and ending points of the arc.

Here is an example of each type:

**Type == Line**

```
"Name": "Line8",
"Type": "Line",
"Start Point": [
                        0.0,
                        -13.694950218796503,
                        127.7623417068559
                    ],
"End Point": [
                        0.0,
                        -12.800696621739458,
                        121.82935674950514
                    ],
"Length": 5.999999999999998
```

**Type == Arc**

```
"Name": "Arc4",
"Type": "Arc",
"CentrePoint": [
                        0.0,
                        0.0,
                        0.0
                    ],
"Radius": 137.0,
"RotationAngle": 0.0,
"StartAngle": 1.5474413367198918,
"EndAngle": 1.5941513168699013,
"Circumference": 6.399267280551308
```

A JSON file will contain multiple such dictionaries for multiple geometric entities that make up a geometric sketch.

I want to create a bounding box around that sketch and need its coordinates.

My initial approach was to just take the min and max values of the x, y and z coordinates from these dictionaries to define a bounding box. But by doing this I might end up missing the curves in the arcs since I only have information about the center of the arc and not the points on the arc.

How should I go about getting the bounding box coordinates given this JSON file?

Comment: If you want the bounding boxes, you'll have to calculate them from the information given for each type — obviously the way you attempted to do it is inadequate for certain types for the reasons stated. Not sure what you are asking…Perhaps you should try [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank You very much. Perhaps my question boils down to this. How do I find the coordinates of points on an arc given the coordinates of the centre and the starting and ending angle of the arc from the horizontal.

Comment: There may be some mathematical way of determining it using the start, stop, and rotation angles since whatever the bbox is will be subset of the bounding box of a full circle (since it's a circular arc). An alternative that might be adequate would be to determine the minimum and maximum coordinates of multiple points that lie on the curve described (the more of them use, the more accurate the answer would be). Again, I suggest asking your question on Mathematics Stack Exchange.